# Delay in file-availability on Windows server

Tags: windows-server-2008-r2, filesystems, windows

I have a Windows 2008 R2 server where I do a lot of processing and store huge data sets. I have several computers all doing local processing, fetching and returning data to the server.

I have noticed that sometimes when I create a file from *machine A* on the server, it can take up to several minutes before *machine X* can see it. It is like that the file is only available to the machine that created it (and perhaps the server).

This means that when *machine X* tries to determine if *machine A* has begun its processing or delivered the results, it might get a wrong answer, since it cannot see the files created by *machine A*.

**What I know:**

- Windows 2008 R2
- No DFS
- Shadow copying each hour
- N x 146GB SAS disks in Raid-5
- Gbit networking
- Clients are Windows 7 x64

**Question:**
I would like some advice to help me narrow down the problem. Is it Windows, is it the file system cache, is it network related or maybe something completely different?

Answer (score 2):

I would take a look at the SMB cache values and how frequently its set to fetch metadata.  This would only be relevant if both machines in each setup were Windows 2008/utilizing SMB2.

http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff686200%28v=ws.10%29.aspx

The part on troubleshooting the impact of these caches may be useful, since a minute or two delay is far beyond the defined times.

Comment: The local computers are all running Windows 7 x64.

Comment: Ah that works too.  SMB2 will run as long as both ends of the connection are running the Vista/7/2008 core.